# Does a word for vending machine shorter than 自販機 exist?

Tags: words, abbreviations

My Japanese teacher told me there is no shorter way to say 自動販売機{じどうはんばいき}. However, I found 自販機{じはんき} in my dictionary. Does a word (including slang) for "vending machine" shorter than four morae exist?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just 自販 without the 機 is quite common.

Comment: Is it new Internet slang? or 若者言葉?

Comment: @Chocolate, from you and TokyoNagoya's comments, it seems obvious that this is not as common as I thought. On the other hand, searching on Google, I'm fairly convinced that there are enough cases that it can't be ascribed to typos. I think I personally picked it up more than 10 years ago in a non-internet context in the Tokyo area.

Comment: 「若者言葉」かも？TokyoNagoyaさんは若者じゃないからきっと知らな（（殴

Answer (score 4):

The wikipedia article for [自動販売機](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%87%AA%E5%8B%95%E8%B2%A9%E5%A3%B2%E6%A9%9F) confirms that 自販機  can be used as a short form but doesn't list any other variants. 販売機{はんばいき} is another option.

The only slang term I know is ガチャ for those capsule vending machines (with little toys or something inside).

Answer (score 3):

Never heard or seen 自販 used as a shortened form of 自動販売機 or 自販機.  (I have lived half of my life in Tokyo and the other half in Nagoya, and I am a Japanese-speaker to begin with.)  The only times I have heard/seen 自販 have been when it was used to mean a "car dealer" （short for 自動車販売）.  I am more than curious to find out why that answer has so many upvotes.

Comment: There are many examples on the internet, e.g. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E8%87%AA%E8%B2%A9%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%8A%22, but given that people don't agree with me that this is common, I'm wondering if its usage is limited in area of time.

Comment: @dainichi でも4ページ目まで行くと、[こう](https://www.google.com/search?q="自販の上"#psj=1&q=%22%E8%87%AA%E8%B2%A9%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%8A%22&start=30)なっちゃうんですよ・・・　　
Googleの謎・・・

Comment: @Chocolate さん、「自動販売機の上」というシチュエーションが限られているからじゃないでしょうか。「の上」をつけたのは、「自動車販売」や「自動販売」じゃなく、「自動販売機」のケースを見つけるためです。"自販機の上"で検索しても、結局243件しか見つかりません。もっといい検索方法があれば教えて下さい。

Comment: It seems to be accepted by at least some dictionaries, .e.g. http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E8%87%AA%E8%B2%A9, that 自販 can be short for 自動販売. My claim that it can be short for 自動販売機 is only based on what I can find on Google and personal experience.

Comment: "自販が"でググると1万以上ヒットしますけど、結構「自動車販売」の意味が多いし・・・[ここ](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=自販ga"&oq=自販ga"&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2.5840j0j9&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=122&espv=210&psj=1&q=%22%E8%87%AA%E8%B2%A9%E3%81%8C%22)　(ところで、その辞書、「自動販売の略」って書いてあるし・・・「自動販売機」じゃなく・・・)

Comment: @dainichi: Google shows a little more than 100 pages that contain “自販のジュース” on the web.  I am afraid that calling it “many examples” is a stretch, but some people use it.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto, searching for "自販のジュース", I find 115 hits. Searching for "自販機のジュース", I find 146 examples (both ignoring "似たページは除外されています"). In a relative sense, I would call that "many".

Comment: @dainichi: I did not think of the possibility that 自販機のジュース would give a similar number.  From these numbers you wrote, I take back my words that calling the results "many" was a stretch.  That does not match my gut feeling about the frequency, but that is a seperate matter.